# My debugger does not show the return values of the programs when the program finishes

Tags: python, debugging

[in the output pane ı cannot see the values that ı entered before when the program finishes (when using debugger). I think, normally ı should see the guess that ı made between the two lines in the output( ı draw an arrow).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TKws.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code so far, maybe you are about to write the logic for it after you have the desired output, but I am anyway going to mention it.

1.If you want the user to guess multiple times you need to use a loop.
For example:

```
while True:
    if ():
        print()
    elif():
        print()
    else:
        print("Correct")
        break
```

2.Also, if you want the user to guess again you would need to take input inside the `if-elif` structure.

3.To print the user input you can do as previous suggestion and put it inside the print-statement inside the if-statement like this:

```
answer = 5
guess = int(input("Please guess a number between 1 and 10:"))

while True:
    if guess < answer:
        print("You guessed:", guess)
        guess = int(input())
    .
    .
    .
    else:
        print("You guessed:", guess)
        print("Congrats, it was correct!")
        break
```

Comment: really helped me to improve my code thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you can add:

```
print(guess)
```

before all the "if" statements if you want to see the input value printed

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked well! But ı thought that the output pane supposed to show me the value (guess) whether ı print "print(guess)" or not. Do you think is there a possibility my debugger is broke?

Comment: it's normal in pycharm debugger. it's not broken

Comment: relieved my concern, thank you, have a nice day.